# Android - PendingIntent does not call onCreate

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Everything is working fine with my GcmListenerService **if the activity is not already running**.

I click on the notification and the app starts with the righ activity, actually `EventHistoryActivity`.

But, if `EventHistoryActivity` is already running, nothing happens.
I expect a call to `onCreate` but it does not happen.

I'm doing this in the `sendNotification` method:

```
resultIntent = new Intent(this, EventHistoryActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("reload", true);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

I tried also `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` but with no luck.

Where is the problem ?

Again, if the app is running but `EventHistoryActivity` is not, all is ok.

Am I doing something wrong or is not `onCreate` the method I should expect to be called ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably getting the call to [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in
>   their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag
>   when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity
>   is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new
>   instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called
>   on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch

Comment: Shame on me, I'm already using `onNewIntent` in the `MainActivity` for the same reason. Tomorrow I test and accept your answer if OK (just to be really sure) now I stop as, obviously, too tired. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This happened to me because I had the singleTask flag on my activity